# Initialize and access <QVector< QVector<int> > QT5

Tags: c++, arrays, qt5, qvector

I have already declared this:

```
//myclass.h
QVector<int> aux;
QVector< QVector<int> > tests;

//myclass.cpp
aux = (QVector<int>(2));
```

and it works ok, but now i want to initialize each **test** QVector dimension into 2 lengths: 20 and 5. Something similar to:

```
tests = (QVector< QVector<int> >(20)(5));
```

but this is not Ok. How can initialize it?.

The second question is how to access **tests** positions using [ ] Is it something similar to this?:

```
tests[1][4]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize it with a size and an object to copy on each one:

```
//Your .h
QVector<int>          aux;
QVector<QVector<int>> tests;

//your .cpp
aux   = QVector<int>(2);
tests = QVector<QVector<int>>(20, aux);
```

Notice that using the aux vector on the tests initialization will not reference(so it will not be modified in the future by accesing tests) it or modify it.
This way tests will have 20 QVectors of size 2 inside.

Relating the second question, it should work with tests[x][y] but if not you can just use .at() method

```
tests.at(x).at(y);
```

Comment: Well, aux and tests are independent variables. I dont want to depend second on the first one. I have declared `QVector< QVector<int> > tests;` in my .h file and i cannot put that initialization there. I need it in my .cpp file.

Comment: @walolinux just use another vector to initialize the test one or use a copy of the aux one

Comment: Ok, but how can i declare it in my .h and set the size in my .cpp?

Comment: im edditing the answer